# restarting IIS (7.5) from a web page

Tags: iis, restart, iisreset

This is purely academic curiosity. Is there a way for me to set up a web page, so that surfing to that page will cause IIS to restart (maybe to execute iisreset)?

Answer (score -1):

Technically, it can be done. :-) I am not giving any pointers here. It is just about calling a process with enough privileges. If you have the privileges on the server, you can do it.

You can in fact crash a worker process quite easily too. Server.Transfer("~/default.aspx", true). [Assuming you are writing this code in page_load of default.aspx.

However, please do not try this on production server.

Comment: If you have pointers why not give them? :-)
You can assume the server is mine and that I have full control over it (I'm not trying to hack or damage anyone)

Comment: Well, it is quite simple... and there are plenty of ways in which you can do it. PowerShell, Writing a batch file and calling it will do. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884939/running-a-batch-file-from-an-asp-net-page.